# How to get an AzureAD JWT for service authentication on command line

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have some company website providing some information protected by azure AD.
This works fine in the browser, but I would like to create some automation on command line.

If I copy the JWT from the browser and use it in the `Authorization: Bearer` header, I can also access that information perfectly fine.

I was also able to use `az login` to prove my identity on the command line.

**What is the correct way to get a suitable JWT on command line in order to access the information?**

I was thinking of something like:

```
az login
token=$(az ad get-new-jwt-token)
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" myinfosite.company.com
```

If there is a better/different solution, I am open to that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  If you want to do this via CLI then it would be like below

1. login
2. set the subscription
3. get the access token

   ```
    az login        
    az account set  -s "<your-subscription-id>"        
    az account get-access-token
   ```

After that you would get your Bearer token
[image]

Comment: Looks like this token is not suitable for authentication in the application, as it is not connected to the OIDC client responsible for that application. If I decode it it shows `"aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/"` instead of `"aud": "51616cb9-xxx"`.